# Django Duration Field with negative value

Tags: python, django

I have a model which contains a `DurationField`. If positive values are saved in this field, I get the correct result, if negative values are saved it returns "None" if I'm trying to access the attribute of the model.

The model looks like the following:

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    nominal_actual_comparison = models.DurationField(null=True,blank = True)
```

If I'm trying to access it now within a view like the following and the value is negative I'm obtaining a `NoneType` object:

```
calendar_object = Calendar.objects.get(id = 1)
calendar_object.nominal_actual_comparison
```

I looked into the database and saw, that the `DurationField` is saved as a `BigInt`. The values in the database are definitely correct, therefore I'm wondering if there is a bug in the implementation of the `DurationField` or am I doing something wrong? What can I do instead? Is it possible to overwrite the `DurationField` class to adapt the way how the `BigInt` gets converted into a `datetime.timedelta` object? I saw a method called `to_python` which apparently calls a `parse_duration` method, but the `to_python` method is somehow never getting called !?
I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue in the meantime by overriding the `DurationField` class.
I had to handle the conversion of the `BigInt` on my own, therefore I had to overwrite the `get_db_converters` method because in the original `DurationField` it calls a method `parse_datetime` which isn't capable of handling negative values obviously. Moreover I had to overwrite `from_db_value` to implement my own conversion of the database value.
The code of my `DurationField` looks like the following now:

```
class DurationField(DurationField):

def get_db_converters(self, connection):
    if hasattr(self, 'from_db_value'):
        return [self.from_db_value]
    return []


def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
    result = ""

    if (value != None):
        d = str(decimal.Decimal(value) / decimal.Decimal(1000000))
        try:
            sec = d.split(".")[0]
            micro_sec = d.split(".")[1]
        except IndexError:
            sec = int(d)
            micro_sec = 0

        result = self.convertSecondsToTimeDelta(seconds = sec, microseconds = micro_sec)
        return result
    else:
        return None

def convertSecondsToTimeDelta(self, seconds = 0 , microseconds = 0):
    return datetime.timedelta(seconds = seconds, microseconds = microseconds)
```